# Explanation on converting the factor variable labels to numeric with same labels values?

Tags: r

Using ISLR library and the  data set.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ISLR)
data("Default")
```

Replacing "No" with 0 and "Yes" with 1 for variables default and student

```
DF1 <- Default %>% 
  select(default, student) %>% 
  mutate(default = factor(default, labels = c("No" = 1, "Yes" = 10)),
         student = factor(student, labels = c("No" = 1, "Yes" = 10)))
```

converting the variables to numeric

```
DF2 <- DF1 %>% 
  mutate(default = as.integer(default),
         student = as.numeric(student))
```

The output is as shown below.

```
> head(DF2)  

  default student
1       1       1
2       1       2
3       1       1
4       1       1
5       1       1
6       1       2
```

While converting to numeric type those 0, 1 values are coded as 1,2 etc.

I got SO answer here.
[How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)

```
DF2 <- DF1 %>% 
  mutate(default = as.integer(levels(default))[default],
         student = as.numeric(levels(student))[student])
> head(DF2)  

  default student
1       0       0
2       0       1
3       0       0
4       0       0
5       0       0
6       0       1
```

Can you please explain a little on the statement

```
as.numeric(levels(student))[student])
```

Why doesn't the instruction below give the desired output?

```
as.numeric(as.factor(student))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Factors are coded as consecutive integers *starting at `1`*. When you use `as.integer` or `as.numeric` directly on the factor, you are getting *those* integers. When you use the former, you are converting the *levels* to numeric, then subsetting with the consecutive integers, the factor values.

Comment: Tip: break `as.numeric(levels(student))[student]` in pieces, first run `as.numeric(levels(student))` then the full instruction.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to break and execute. This helps!